# Auto labeling algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a set of points (2D space), and for every point there's a label (like city names on a map).
I want to find a real-time algorithm that allows labels to avoid overlapping, moving them from their original position if necessary.

I've heard about simulated annealing algorithm, but I can't find a good source to learn how to do this. Do you have some idea where I can find bibliography and practical examples?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Googling "simulated annealing" gives me a load of good hits, including the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) (which gives pseudocode) and an [overview by Bertsimas](http://web.mit.edu/dbertsim/www/papers/Optimization/Simulated%20annealing.pdf). If you don't consider these to be good sources, you really need to be more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: Thanks... I'm actually watching also this. I'm looking for performance because labels must be aligned in a real-time map environment (where user can zoom-pan and objects can be moved).